# How I can make website that compile & run C++ program online

Tags: php, c++

I have been seen many website that compile and run C++ program online
I want make a website using php that applied the same idea 
if there any help as possible to do that.. I will be thankful 
Knowing i want to applied input & output statement.

Comment: ideone has something for that.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify what your **specific question** is?  It's only clear that you want to make a website and that site *applies an idea*.

Comment: **DON'T.** The way that you are asking this question implies that you are not cognizant of the inherent major security issues involved in creating and running such a site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might mean running an external exe? something like shell_exec?

[shell_exec function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

or do you mean google native client to run your code inside the browser?

[Google Native Client](https://developers.google.com/native-client/)

Answer (score 3):

You should be **very, very careful** about letting users compile and run C/C++ code on your server, as they could abuse your trust and use it as an easy way to get access to your system. So unless you're sure that only users can access the script who you'd also trust enough to give them ssh access, **do not do this**.

Anyway, a simple way to do it would be to write the user code into a temporary file, run the compiler and the program with something like [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), print the output and delete the temporary source code file and executable.

Something completely different would be a compiler emulated on the client side with something like [Fabrice Bellard's Javascript PC Emulator](http://bellard.org/jslinux/). As everything happens on the client side here, it should be pretty safe. Of course it has other problems, e.g. performance.